# Can I use stream_results on SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.stream_results

As stated in above document, for connection or statement, the result can be "streamed".

e.g.

```
records = connection.execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(
  'select * from large_table'
)
for rec in records:
    process_it(rec)
```

On rdb connectors which supports this option, above command would fetch rows as needed, thus saving memory usage.

---

Now I have `Session` class through which I can connect database and query objects.

I want to execute following command, and would like to "stream" the row fetching also.

```py
session = Session()

# I want this to be streamed!
model_objects = session.query(SomeModel).all()

# So that objects gets fetched and initialized "On Demand"
for model_obj in model_objects:
    process(model_obj)
```

#### Question:

- Is it possible to apply `stream_results` option against ORM query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `stream_results=True` type of behavior, you want the ORM `yield_per(count)` method.
This conserves memory when fetching very large result sets.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.yield_per

> Yield only `count` rows at a time.